# jQuery append once to each div

Tags: jquery, angularjs, append

I'm developing a YouTube widget in ServiceNow's Service Portal and am running into a problem with .append.  Append is appending iframes to my div multiple times, but I only want it to append once.  My HTML and Client Side code is below:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
    <span class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-{{c.glyph}}" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; {{c.title}}</span>
  </div>

    <div class="fluidMedia"></div>
  </div>
```

Client Script:

```
   function($scope,$sce,spModal) {
        var c = this;

        //Get option values
        c.title = c.options.title || 'Training Video';
        c.glyph = c.options.glyph || 'youtube';
        //c.video = c.options.video_url;

        console.log('Options');
        console.log(c.options);

        c.server.get().then(function(r) {
            console.log('Response');
            console.log(r);
            c.data.video = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(r.data.video);
            $('div .fluidMedia').append('<iframe class="media" src='+ c.data.video +' frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>')
        });
    }
```

In my console I see this, the 3 videos are basically layered on top of one another because all of them are being appended to div.fluidMedia.  How would I get it so that a different video is appended to each div.fluidMedia?  Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*How would I get it so that a different video is appended to each div.fluidMedia?*

"Each div.fluidMedia". There is only one. You either want 1 div.fluidMedia, which replaces the iframe every time, you get a new video.

```
$('.fluidMedia iframe').empty();
$('div .fluidMedia').append('<iframe class="media" src='+ c.data.video +' frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>')
```

or
multiple divs with class "fluidmedia"

```
$(.panel).append('<div class="fluidMedia"><iframe class="media" src='+ c.data.video +' frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>');
```